# How do I load expl3 without LaTeX (or any other format)?

Tags: expl3

```
\input expl3-generic %

hello, world

\bye
```

gives me `\inf` errors about undefined control sequences when processed with `tex`.

When processed with `initex`, I'm greeted with an even more puzzling error (given the very simple beginnings of `expl3-generic`):

```
$ initex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2014) (INITEX)
**\input expl3-generic
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-generic.tex)
Runaway definition?
{expl3} \def \ExplFileDescription {L3 programming layer} \def \ExplFileDate \ET
C.
! File ended while scanning definition of \ExplFileName.
<inserted text> 
                }
<*> \input expl3-generic

? Q
OK, entering \batchmode
```

Comment: As for initex, it looks like `{` and `}` aren't set up yet. Setting these catcodes doesn't completely solve the issue though; errors are just thrown later down the line.

Comment: Could you edit in the error you get loading with plain? It should work fine (and indeed does here). On using iniTeX, we've not tested that and I don't think expect it to work: there are all sorts of things not set up in iniTeX and the only reason for loading `expl3` there is when building a format (you can build a format using the LaTeX3 sources but it doesn't do much!).

Comment: The key to type in order to kill a TeX job is `x`, not `q` (lowercase or uppercase are the same).

Comment: @JosephWright you get `! Extra \fi.
l.336   \fi` if you don't use etex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You need not only e-TeX but also `\pdfstrcmp` or equivalent. I guess I'll have to re-check the start-up tests that look for that: they should stop you shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I eventually figured that out last night :) Took a while for me to slow down and actually *read* what TeX was telling me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`expl3` needs etex, so you need to use `etex` not `tex` or `initex --etex`.

Comment: Thanks :) I'd assumed `tex` was linked to `etex`, but I was obviously mistaken :)

Comment: Perhaps that should be assured by the generic loader

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Perhaps, yes. I don't think there are any real downsides with regard to archivability. Someone typesetting a document that old would likely also know where to find a wizard if need be.

Comment: @SeanAllred pdftex is, as are most other formats but texlive sets `tex` up to be classic tex with no extensions, in deference to its creator.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I suppose that is the polite thing to do :)